# Tools for developing iOS apps with Adobe AIR?

Tags: ios, air, adobe

I already have some apps created with Adobe AIR on Android market and I'm planning to use Adobe AIR to create apps for iOS.

It will be very helpfully for me and others like me to share some resources that you use to create AIR apps for iOS. By resources I mean: Softwares to emulate iOS devices or maybe other softwares that are needed, and so on...

Do you need extra expenses beside market's fee ?

What tools do you use to develop or test iOS apps on Windows, except Flash AIR ?

Any other informations will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simulate iOS devices, you need a Mac with XCode on it.

Answer (score 0):

I used the build in emulator and real devices (most often). Although not totally related but use Adobe Scout for debugging (all kinds of info like network calls, gpu rendering etc.) on real devices **very** helpful since you don't have Xcode's Instruments at you disposal.